# Weird line breaks after removing whitespaces

Tags: php, regex, curl

I'm using cURL to get the content of a site. I want to remove ALL whitespaces and line breaks from the string. This is what I'm doing:

```
// Getting the content
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

// Removing html tags
$content = strip_tags($content);

// Removing whitespaces
$content = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $content);
```

When I echo the content I get line breaks only after special characters like these: `=),.?}`
I have tried removing the line breaks with `str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r"), "\n", $content);` but it doesn't work. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Tell me, do you really want to remove all whitespace, and not just to compress the repeating one?

Comment: What do you mean compress the repeating one?